# What is Pandas Rolling Mean Algorithm with 1m Data and Time Offset 1hr

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, moving-average, rolling-computation

I am trying to figure out the algorithm pandas is using for the rolling mean with time offset because I am getting unexpected results when I compute it manually.

My data is formatted in a data frame with values at 1 minute granularity as follows:

```sh
Datetime            Values
2018-02-02 21:27:00 3175.068017
2018-02-02 21:28:00 3163.183960
2018-02-02 21:29:00 3175.972021
2018-02-02 21:30:00 3188.535987
2018-02-02 21:31:00 3192.447974
```

The dtypes for the columns are:

```sh
Datetime is datetime64[ns]
Values is float64
```

Sometimes the time series is irregular (a minute - or more - is skipped) so I am trying to use the time offset for the rolling mean. I want 1hr rolling mean and the command I use is:

```py
df.rolling('H').mean()
```

My understanding is that this defaults to `min_periods=1`. I tried with 1 minute rolling mean already and I got back what I expected. But for the 1hr, I don't get what I expect but I don't know what algorithm it is using either.

So with `min_periods=1`, I am expecting the calculation to be:

```sh
Datetime              Avg         Interval
2018-02-02 21:27:00   3216.71147  [21:27-22:26]
2018-02-02 21:28:00   3217.57497  [21:28-22:27]
2018-02-02 21:29:00   3219.08083  [21:29-22:28]
```

Instead pandas gives me:

```sh
Datetime            Avg
2018-02-02 21:27:00 3175.068017 # Same as Raw
2018-02-02 21:28:00 3169.125989
2018-02-02 21:29:00 3171.408000
2018-02-02 21:30:00 3175.689996
```

I thought maybe it's assuming `21:00-21:59` but the average of the values in that window is `3190.77915`. I am basically just trying to determine what pandas is actually doing for my 1m data at a 1H rolling mean granularity because it's not what I expect.

Comment: It doesn't look forward, it looks backward. SO your mean for `21:28` is `20:28-21:28`

Comment: @RafaelC Wow, I feel silly but thank you SOOOOO much!